# Do Not Output Trailing Zeroes in C++

Tags: c++, c

If the result is an integer, **do not** output the decimal point.

If the result is a floating point number, **do not** output any trailing zeroes.

How to do it in `c` or`c++`:

```
double result;
/*some operations on result */
printf("%g", result);
```

Is the above approach correct?  I'm not getting the correct answer with in my situation.

Comment: In C or C++? Different languages, different solutions.

Comment: What output do you get? Show some samples.

Comment: a double is almost never an integer.. but it can be really close to one. what's the precision you need?

Comment: Um, if you're not getting "the correct answer", then by definition your approach is not correct...

Comment: ok say c++ , precision??? i just need to remove trailing zeroes...so if the result is 100.0 output should be 100 and if it is 100.510 output should be 100.51

Comment: @sachin: And if it's `100.5100000000000045` ?

Comment: i think zeroes after 51 are not trailing zeroes..so 100.5100000000000045 would be ans...

Answer (score 4):

you can use `snprintf` to print the double value into a char array, then from the end to the head, replace the '0' with '\0', finally you get a the number without tailling zeroes.Here is my simple code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void
remove_zeroes(double number, char * result, int buf_len)
{ 
    char * pos;
    int len;

    snprintf(result, buf_len, "%lf", number);
    len = strlen(result);

    pos = result + len - 1;
 #if 0
/* according to Jon Cage suggestion, removing this part */
    while(*div != '.')
        div++;
#endif
    while(*pos == '0')
        *pos-- = '\0';

    if(*pos == '.')
        *pos = '\0';

}

int
main(void)
{
    double a;
    char test[81];

    a = 10.1;

    printf("before it is %lf\n", a);
    remove_zeroes(a, test, 81);
    printf("after it is %s\n", test);

    a = 100;
    printf("before it is %lf\n", a);
    remove_zeroes(a, test, 81);
    printf("after it is %s\n", test);


    return 0;
}
```

and the output is

```
before it is 10.100000
after it is 10.1
before it is 100.000000
after it is 100
```

Comment: @JonCage, yes, I miss that situation,  now I have updated the code.:)

Comment: It would be more efficient to simply check whether the last character is a '.' after removing zero's instead of always working out where the . is and comparing.

Comment: @JonCage, haha, I wrote that code without thinking the efficiency, I fix it with your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer readable code and this will work and be easy to understand. It requires boost though.

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

std::string value = std::to_string((double)12); //yields 12.000000
boost::trim_right_if(value, boost::is_any_of("0")); //turn 12.000000 -> 12.
boost::trim_right_if(value, boost::is_any_of(".")); //turn 12. -> 12
```

Note that the code below will work for 12 it will not work for 120 or 0. You must trim it two steps to not remove zeros to the immediate left of the decimal point. So don't try to save a line!

```
std::string value = std::to_string((double)120);
boost::trim_right_if(value, boost::is_any_of("0.")); //yields 12 not 120
```

It was pointed out to me in the comments that 6 digit precision might not be enough. Then try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

std::stringstream sStream;
sStream << std::fixed << std::setprecision( 16 ) << (double)12; //yields 12.0000000000000000
std::string value = sStream.str();
boost::trim_right_if(value, boost::is_any_of("0")); //turn 12.000000000000000 -> 12.
boost::trim_right_if(value, boost::is_any_of(".")); //turn 12. -> 12
```

Comment: This cuts all floating point numbers to six desimal places. OP wrote that `100.5100000000000045` should not become `100.51`.

Comment: I think that is really a separate question. How to increase the precision in the conversion. But non the less. I updated my answer for a variant with 16 digit precision.

Comment: This doesn' t work for me, check this exampel : https://ideone.com/t68y0L

Comment: Well, that's how double works. In your example you use 16 digit precision. Try lowering the precision to get the rounding error cut off. And then trim it.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the result is an integer, you could either use an integer variable or simply cast to an integer:

```
double result;
/*some operations on result */
printf("%d", (int)result);
```

**[Edit]** Try something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
void VariablePrecisionPrinter( double num, double precision )
{
    if( fabs(num-int(num)) < precision )
    {
        printf("%d\n", (int) num);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%g\n", num);
    }
}

void Test(  )
{
    const double Precision = 0.001;
    VariablePrecisionPrinter( 100.001, Precision );
    VariablePrecisionPrinter( 100.00001, Precision );
    VariablePrecisionPrinter( 0.00001, Precision );
    VariablePrecisionPrinter( 0.0, Precision );
    VariablePrecisionPrinter( 0.1, Precision );
}
```

...which will print:

```
100.001
100
0
0
0.1
```

**[Edit2]**

This is a bit clunky but it does what you ask:

```
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

void VariablePrecisionPrinter( double num )
{
    // Convert the number to a string
    const int tmpSize = 128;
    char tmp[tmpSize] = {'\0'};
    sprintf(tmp, "%lf", num);
    string truncatedNum = tmp;

    // If the conversion ends with a 0, strip the extra parts.
    size_t p2 = truncatedNum.find_last_not_of( '0' );
    if( string::npos != p2 )
    {
        truncatedNum = truncatedNum.substr( 0, p2+1 );

        // Make sure we're not left with just a decimal point at the end
        size_t decimalPos = truncatedNum.find_last_of('.');
        if( decimalPos == truncatedNum.length()-1  )
        {
            truncatedNum = truncatedNum.substr( 0, truncatedNum.length()-1 );
        }
    }

    printf( "%s\n", truncatedNum.c_str() );
}

void Test(  )
{
    const double Precision = 0.001;
    VariablePrecisionPrinter( 100.001 );
    VariablePrecisionPrinter( 100.00001 );
    VariablePrecisionPrinter( 0.00001 );
    VariablePrecisionPrinter( 0.0 );
    VariablePrecisionPrinter( 0.1 );
}
```

Comment: and what about double will printf("%f", result); not carry trailing zeroes? i think it will carry trailing zeroes say result is 100.00100 then printf will print 100.00100 but i want output as 100.001.

Answer (score 0):

For the compiler `result` is always a double because it's declared as such. Internally it has a different memory layout than an integer.

To do properly what you want to achieve check if `result` is close enough to a natural number and cast it to an appropriate integer before printing.

Answer (score 0):

```
string DoubleToString (double inValue)
{
   std::stringstream buildString;

   int i = 0;
   double valueWithPrecision = 0;

   do
   {
      buildString.str(std::string());
      buildString.clear();

      buildString << std::fixed << std::setprecision(i) << inValue;

      valueWithPrecision  = std::stod(buildString.str().c_str());

      i++;
   } while (valueWithPrecision  != inValue);

   return buildString.str();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays you should just insert one line for the manipulator:

```
cout << noshowpoint;
cout << 12.000000000000000 << endl;
```

Alternatively insert this manipulation just before your output (as oneliner) if its not even the default.

If you like the other way around, then `showpoint` is your friend.