# Float to string without trailing zeros

Tags: c++

What's the recommended way to format a float to a string without trailing zeros?
`to_string()` returns `"1.350000"` as does `sprintf`. I don't want a fixed amount of decimals...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
        string s = to_string(1.35);
        cout << s << endl;
}
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, it's not possible with string format specifiers, however there's always a solution to remove them manually from resulting string. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277772/avoid-trailing-zeroes-in-printf

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to output float to cout without scientific notation or trailing zeros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18881854/how-to-output-float-to-cout-without-scientific-notation-or-trailing-zeros)

Answer (score 5):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    stringstream ss;
    ss << 1.35;
    cout << ss.str();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`std::to_string` & `sprintf` does not give you any power to control the number of trailing zero you get when converting a float to a string. Try using `std::stringstream` instead, you'll have all the options you need to control the trailing zeros.